# Inner meaning of Ein k'Eloheinu

Tags: tefilla

In our daily prayers we find, "Ein k'Eloheinu" - "There's no one like our G-d"[Ben Ish chai](https://www.sefaria.org/Ben_Ish_Hai%2C_Halachot_1st_Year%2C_Ki_Tisa.18.1?lang=en&with=all&lang2=en) mentions that there are big kabbalistic intentions in it.

1. What is the inner meaning of the prayer?
2. What are the intentions.

Comment: Is this in all customs of daily prayer? (Meaning do all nuschu’os include this?)

Comment: I believe it's fairly common among Sephardim (@Rh tends to hold by Sephardic halacha, @mroll)

Comment: I don't understand the difference between your two questions.

Comment: Compare Megillah 14a on the similar phrase אין צור כאלקינו from Shmuel 1:2:2 - “Man fashions a form on the wall but can’t place in it a breath or soul, innards or intestines, but Hashem fashions a form inside a form and places in it a breath and soul, innards and intestines.” Just posting as a comment because אין כאלקינו may be broader since it doesn’t make reference to Hashem as the Fashioner of life, but perhaps someone connects the two.

Answer (score 4):

*En Kelohenu* calls God by four names in the order in which they appear in the Torah (Elokim, Adonenu, Melech, Moshia) [Genesis 1:1, 15:2, Exodus 15:18, Deuteronomy 33:29], symbolizing the four worlds of the kabbalah.

Source: pp 214-5 of Rabbi Donin's *To Pray as a Jew*.